# Concurrent file access in nfsv4 linux c

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, file-io, nfs, file-locking

Using C, running under Linux, I am trying to figure out how to have 2 different processes access the same file located on an NFSv4 filesystem.  Specifically, I want to have one program fopen a file for reading, and have a second program fopen the file for writing.  I am intending use the new EFS (Elastic File System) from AWS, and EFS is only NFSv4.

The nature of the programs is such that the writer will, in essence, only be appending to the file.  The reader will never access the newly-appended info until the writer has finished and called fflush.

Does NFSv4 support this scenario?

Or is there a better way altogether to achieve such concurrent NFSv4 file access?

Comment: *Does NFSv4 support this scenario?* I have no idea. Why not use shared memory with [ipcs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipcs)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch:  I could use shared memory with ipcs, but there is a massive amount of data (>  500 terabytes) in a massive number of files (> 40 million).  And growing.

Comment: Then it sounds like you should be looking at [HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#Overview).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: I edited my question to reflect fact that AWS ElasticFileSystem only runs under NFSv4

Comment: and are the 2 processes running on the same machine? If so file mapping is almost certainly the way to go.

Comment: @camelccc The 2 processes are running on different AWS nodes.  And not sure file mapping will work with 40 million files and 500 tb of data.

Comment: the different nodes complicates things mapping wise. fopen is limited in the number of files it can open at a time  -1024 being the default file handle limit. Mapping has no limit that I know of, but has less limits than any other method I know of accessing files. How many files do you need open at a time? if more than a thousand or so mapping is the about the only way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFS v4 does support byte range locking on files (as outlined in this excerpt from [RFC 3530 "NFS version 4 protocol"](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3530.txt)):

> **1.4.5.  File locking**
>
> With the NFS version 4 protocol, the support for byte range file locking is part of the NFS protocol. The file locking support is structured so that an RPC callback mechanism is not required. This is a departure from the previous versions of the NFS file locking protocol, Network Lock Manager (NLM). The state associated with file locks is maintained at the server under a lease-based model. The server defines a single lease period for all state held by a NFS client. If the client does not renew its lease within the defined period, all state associated with the client's lease may be released by the server. The client may renew its lease with use of the `RENEW` operation or implicitly by use of other operations (primarily `READ`).

Refer to section 8 of the same RFC for greater detail on locking and the lease-based model.

Your program will need to use `fcntl` to manage locking. My advice is to write a test to check that the actual implementation of NFS v4 provided by EFS supports locking as expected (some aspects are optional in the specification). You can refer to the source code of [this lock testing suite](https://github.com/linux-test-project/ltp/tree/master/testcases/network/nfsv4/locks), which supports multi-client testing.

Comment: @Paenelnsula did you run the experiment what were your findings have same scenario with my application which is more like WAL